# Using .Find to looking for value "14:00" time

Tags: excel, vba, time, find

I found this problem on two different PC with different worksheets and Excel Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus  version.

I have a column with this values in cells:

> 8:00
>
> 8:30
>
> 9:00
>
> 9:30
>
> 10:00
>
> 10:30
>
> 11:00
>
> 11:30
>
> 12:00
>
> 12:30
>
> 13:00
>
> 13:30
>
> 14:00
>
> 14:30
>
> 15:00
>
> 15:30
>
> 16:00
>
> 16:30
>
> 17:00
>
> 17:30

The cells are formatted as time ("*hh:mm")

I make a search, with .find function, looking for a time value with this VBA code:

```
TimeToFind= "08:00"
Set Position=worksheets("Foglio1").Range("E5:E21").Find(TimeValue(TimeToFind), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

All gone since I change then string TimeToFind with the "14:00" or "14:30" value.

When I change the string with these two values Position return the cell that contains "12:00" (instead "14:00") and a"12:30" (instead "14:30").
The problem happened with just this two values. Every other value gives the correct cell.

Someone find same problem or can replicate it?

Thanks

EDIT:
**I tried the search also on Excel 2016 Versione with same results.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find):

> The settings for *LookIn*, *LookAt*, *SearchOrder*, and *MatchByte*
>   are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values
>   for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved
>   values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the
>   **Find** dialog box, and changing the settings in the **Find** dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments.
>   To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use
>   this method.

So last time you had used **Find** dialog box you had not checked "Match entire cell contents". So it used partial seach. `VBA` always is `en_US`. So for 14:00 it searches 2:00:00 PM and this is contained in 12:00:00 PM. Same for 14:30 = 2:30:00 PM and 12:30:00 PM. Thats why a partial search for 2:00:00 PM finds 12:00:00 PM.

So we need `LookAt:=xlWhole` here:

```
TimeToFind= "14:00"
Set Position=worksheets("Foglio1").Range("E5:E21").Find(TimeValue(TimeToFind), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: @Alexstb - it's good use to accept a helpful solution by ticking the green checkmark as it may give some orientation to other users, too :-)